# php -> sql - validate unique table entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got an issue / question regarding unique table id´s. I am passing data from PHP -> SQL and use $id as primary key:

```
$id = new DateTime();
$id = $id -> format("dmYHis");
// example - 15102021102640 (15.10.2021-10:26:40)
```

I am afraid users could generate the same Id in future, which might crash the application or database. Would it be a good practice to validate the uniqueness within the related SQL insert statement? Like so, further please ignore SQL injection for now:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [trans1]
                            BEGIN TRY
                            INSERT INTO table1 (id) VALUES ('$id');
                            // pseudo code
                            // validate uniqueness
                            // while $id exist do $id + 1 else continue
                            // validate uniqueness   
                            COMMIT TRANSACTION [trans1];
                            END TRY
                            BEGIN CATCH
                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [trans1]
                            END CATCH";
```

I am not sure if a validation check, during this SQL statement would fix the security concerns.

Comment: Why aren't you using database-generated identity columns? You're correct to be concerned, at some point in the future (probably many times) application-generated identity values are going to let you down. What happens when you start having load balanced front end servers that have even just a few milliseconds of clock drift between each other?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning well, nothing stops me to utilize database-generated identities. My thoughts were to be able to read the timestamp directly from the id. Your comment already helped me to look into a different direction. I will change it.